# Implementing CDF (or inverse of CDF) in AMPL

Tags: optimization, ampl, ipopt

my question involved some mathematics so I typed in Latex format and took a screen shot of it.
[image]

I wonder how I can implement this in AMPL. In Matlab fmincon, you can easily pass CDF ( or inverse of CDF) but I don't know how in AMPL we can do this. Is there any way that I can implement function of CDF ( or inverse of CDF) in AMPL.

Answer (score 0):

AMPL has a extended function library available at https://ampl.com/resources/extended-function-library/ that can be used to implement PDF and CDF function.